# If we expand the definition of the general quadratic $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$ to include the case $a=0$, can we arrive at a general solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

Through a simple mathematical substitution, I have stumbled upon an alternative formula for solving a quadratic equation:

$$x=\frac{2c}{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}$$

(Please refer to my formula derivation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2acjW.png); this is my first question, so cannot include images yet).

I am not aware if this has been mentioned elsewhere.

I was just curious for a formula that reduces to the linear solution ($x=-\frac{c}{b}$) for the standard quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, if we allow the case $a=0$. The standard solution formula $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}$crashes for $a=0$ because division by zero is not allowed.

This alternative formula $x=\frac{2c}{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}$covers the case $a=0$, wherein it reduces to the linear equation $(bx + c = 0)$ solution ($x=-\frac{c}{b}$) for the negative square root of the discriminant, but the positive square root of the discriminant needs to be ignored/is a problem in that case.

What are your thoughts? Can we arrive at a general formula for a quadratic equation which includes all the cases ($a=0$ and/or $b=0$ and/or $c=0$)?

Comment: It’s a very interesting thought process, at least.

Comment: These are the same formula, arrived at by multiplication by conjugate

Comment: One comment is that if $c=0$, I think the alternative formula could miss a nonzero solution.

Comment: The problem is: $a+by+cy^2=0$ with $a=0$, since in this case $y=0$ is a solution that we can’t have by construction.

Comment: @littleO Thanks. Yes for $c=0$ there's an issue. I look at my solution as a step towards the final formula.

Comment: @kevinkayaks True. I had realized that later.

Comment: @Mario not sure what you mean... can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: The standard solution formula does not really *crash* when $a = 0$. Assume that $b > 0$. On the one hand $|x_-| \to + \infty$ as $a \to 0$ (but this is expected, since there is only one solution). On the other hand $x_+ \to -c/b$ as $a \to 0$ (as can be checked by writing $\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \approx b(1 - 2 ac / b^2)$), so the formula can be extended by continuity.

Comment: We could aim for a solution to the quartic case which copes with the degenerate cubic, quadratic, and linear cases.  That would make life simpler.

Comment: FYI, this alternate form is often called the [Citardauq Formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Citardauq+Formula%22&filter=0) (not sure when this name began -- possibly [this 1976 paper](https://pubs.nctm.org/view/journals/mt/69/7/article-p550.xml)), and one can find it in algebra texts (for numerically calculating roots when the quadratic coefficient is close to zero) at least as far back as the mid 1800s. With the rise of electronic computers (since mid 1940s), it's [fairly widely known in CS](https://www.google.com/search?q=Forsythe+%22Solving+a+quadratic+equation+on+a+computer%22).

Comment: @cs89 didn't fully comprehend your answer, but I believe it as true as far as I can understand. However, the facts that you stated seem to be non-obvious... was looking for a simple obvious solution formula (e.g. one that a high school student can understand) here.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro that was indeed wonderful to know. Thanks a lot for sharing and for the links!

Comment: @AndroidGuy, In your calculation you pose $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and so $y\neq 0$, but when you obtain $by+cy^2$ (the case $a=0$) there is the solution $y=0$ that you cannot consider. So you obtain a problem for $a=0$ in $x=\frac{2c}{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}$. In other word, if $a=0$, $y=0$ and so $x=\infty$. This explain why you have to consider $-b \pm b$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Mario I had put the condition $x\neq0$ and never thought about $y\neq0$, your opinion made me aware of this additional requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the homogeneous case where we are working with points $(x:y)$ on the complex projective line and consider the homogeneous equation $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=0.$$ The solutions are $$(x:y)=(-b \pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}:2a)$$ and this works as long as $a,b,c$ are not all $0.$

Comment: [+1] This is more or less the algebraic equivalent of @cs89's comment invoking limits.

Comment: Hardly understood anything from this answer. Kindly forgive my mathematical incompetency.